# Nginx not honoring proxy_cache_valid

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx cache configure as follows:

```
location / {
    rewrite  ^/(.*)$  /$1  break;
    proxy_pass http://news;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Protocol http;
    proxy_read_timeout 480;
    proxy_connect_timeout 480;
    set $cache_key  "$uri";
    proxy_cache my-cache;
    proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
    proxy_cache_valid  200 302  10m;
    proxy_cache_valid  404      30s;
    proxy_cache_methods GET;
    add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
```

}

When I check the `x-cache-status` header of the response the second time its value is `HIT`. The problem is that the after about 20 seconds the response is giving `MISS`. The http response code is 200. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Be aware of the `inactive=time` setting in the nginx.conf for proxy_cache_path. Proxy_cache_invalid does not override this value.